# How to do GEE with LS means in R

Tags: generalized-estimating-equations, lsmeans

I've done a GEE analysis for a dataset in SPSS and I want to replicate the analysis in R, but I'm fairly new to R so I'm not sure how to do it.
Here's a list of all the things I included in SPSS:

- independent correlation matrix
- robust estimator for covariance matrix
- Gamma (log link) model
- I also want to calculate estimated marginal means (aka LSmeans) to find in what session the session:s.n:d.h interaction becomes significant. Multiple comparisons are adjusted by least significant differences.

In this dataset I want to see if latency changes across sessions and depends on the dehydration state (d.h), presence of saline (s.n), and batch. I want session, d.h, and s.n as fixed factors and batch as a covariate.
Here is the code I have done so far:

```
#gee
mazegee.lat = geeglm(latency~s.n*d.h*session + batch, id=id, 
    family=Gamma(link="log"), waves=session, data=mazedata, 
    corstr="independence")
summary(mazegee.lat)

#I needed a separate gee so assign session as a fixed factor so lsmeans will 
#look at each session separately
mazegee.lat2 = geeglm(latency~s.n*d.h*factor(session) + batch, id=id, 
    family=Gamma(link="log"), data=mazedata, waves=session, 
    corstr="independence")
summary(mazegee.lat2)

#increases max amount of rows to display for below analysis
options(max.print = 1000000)

#pairwise estimated marginal means
maze.emm = lsmeans(mazegee.lat2, pairwise~session*s.n*d.h)
summary(maze.emm)
```

From this I get values but they're all very off, for example the p values in the lsmeans analysis are mostly 1 or close to 1 and the lsmeans are way too low (mostly around 6 instead of being in the 100s like it should be since latency is measured up to 300 seconds), so obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Any help with this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to add `type = "response")` to the `lsmeans()` call? Without it, the results are computed on the scale of the link function used in the gee (in this case, the log). The annotations in the lsmeans output are intended to remind people of this, but I've found that often people don't notice them. This won't change the p values however.

Comment: @rvl I added it to ref.grid() command instead and it worked! Like you said the p values are still really high, but at least one thing was fixed, thanks!

Comment: I know it's pretty late to be responding. But one issue you have is that you are looking at pairwise comparisons among *all* factor combinations. I suggest using `lsmip` to obtain a graphical display of the results, and then follow-up with only the comparisons that really matter. Get just the EMMs first: `maze.emm = lsmeans(mazegee.lat2, ~session*s.n*d.h, type = "response")`. Then follow-up with, for example, `pairs(maze.emm, by = c("s.n", "d.h"))`. This will make the multiplicity adjustments over a much smaller family, hence the P values may not be as big.

Comment: BTW, those comparisons are done on the log scale, so that when back-transformed, they are ratios. I think that is best, but if you want differences instead of ratios, use `regrid` instead of `type` in the `lsmeans` call.